# Meteor: Make Meteor.method return a callback

Tags: methods, meteor, callback

New to Meteor, and I love it so far. I use vzaar.com as video hosting platform, and they have a node.js package/API which I added to my Meteor project with meteorhacks:npm. Everything in the API works great, but when I upload a video, I need to fetch the video ID from the API when successfully uploaded.

## Problem:

I need to save the video id returned from the vzaar API after uploading, but since it happens in the future, my code does not wait on the result and just gives me "undefined". **Is it possible to make the Meteor.method wait for the response?**

Here is my method so far:

```
Meteor.methods({

    vzaar: function (videopath) {

        api.uploadAndProcessVideo(videopath, function (statusCode, data) {
            console.log("Video ID: " + data.id);
            return data.id;

        }, {
            title: "my video",
            profile: 3
        });

        console.log(videoid);

    }

});
```

And this is how the Meteor.call looks like right now:

```
Meteor.call("vzaar", "/Uploads/" + fileInfo.name, function (err, message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

When I call this method, I immediately get `undefined` in browser console and meteor console, and after some seconds, I get the video ID in the meteor console.

Comment: You could write a new function there that would rerun if `videoid` is undefined and pass it as a callback (only helps with callback if you parse the data multiple ways). You can also call the same function you're inside. You could also try polling where you set an interval to check every n milliseconds then clear the interval when `videoid` is set.

Comment: I found something interesting, Meteor.wrapAsync. A article about it here, but I have no clue how to implement it in my code. https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I finally solved the problem, after days of trial and error. I learned about Fibers ([here](https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html) and [here](http://phucnguyen.info/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-async-meteor/)), and learned more about the core event loop of Node.js. The problem were that this call answered in the future, so my code always returned `undefined` because *it ran before* the api had answered.

I first tried the Meteor.wrapAsync, which I thought were going to work, as it is actually the Future fiber. But I ended up using the raw NPM module of Future instead. See this working code:

```
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
Meteor.methods({

    vzaar: function (videopath) {

        var fut = new Future();
        api.uploadAndProcessVideo(videopath, function (statusCode, data) {

            // Return video id
            fut.return (data.id);
        }, {
            // Video options
            title: "hello world",
            profile: 3
        });

        // The delayed return
        return fut.wait();

    }

});
```

Remember to install the npm module correctly with [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) first.

I learned about how to use the Future fiber in this case via [this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763601/1554299)

I hope this can be useful for others, as it was really easy to implement.